# Show SOME invisible/whitespace characters in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tabs, spaces, bbedit

A long while back I transitioned to doing all my web application development in Eclipse from BBEdit. But I miss one little feature from BBEdit. I used to be able to show invisible characters like tabs but not show other invisibles like spaces. I know that I can bulk turn all of these on in Eclipse, but I wonder if there is a way to show only some invisibles in Eclipse.

Comment: Incase anyone in the future lands on this page like I did looking for how to show white space in eclipse it is: Window>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors

Comment: Update: Eclipse has this ability from 3.7M3 version. You can adjust the visibility of space, tab, cr and lf individually.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, you can only turn on all invisible (whitespace) characters at the same time. I suggest you file an enhancement request but I doubt they will pick it up.</s>

The text component in Eclipse is very complicated as it is and they are not keen on making them even worse.

**[UPDATE]** This has been fixed in Eclipse 3.7: Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors

Click on the link at *☑ Show whitespace characters ([configure visibility](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-texteditorprefs.htm))* to fine tune what should be shown.

Kudos go to [John Isaacks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46011/john-isaacks)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's nice to know that this is probably a fixed issue. I will go ahead and search out the Eclipse issue system and file a request.

Comment: Now that Eclipse Indigo is out, this answer is no longer accurate. See John's comment on the original question.

Answer (score 54):

Navigate to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors

Click on the CheckBox "Show whitespace characters".

[image]

Thats all.!!!

Answer (score 29):

I would prefer to keep the "Show Whitespace" button on the toolbar, so that in one click you can toggle it.

Go to Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective and enable to show the button on toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I even tried to search for 'word wrap' in context menu but couldn't find it in Neon. This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I use Checkstlye plugin for such a purpose. In Checkstyle configuration, I add special regexp rules to detect lines with TABs and then mark such lines as checkstyle ERROR, which is clearly visible in Eclipse editor. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

AnyEdit
Scroll all the way down: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/examples.html

Comment: GitX (mac) can also highlight whitespace error in commit screen.