# Show whitespace in Eclipse for specific editors/file types

Tags: eclipse, whitespace

I know how to turn on white-space visualization [wholesale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364168/show-some-invisible-whitespace-characters-in-eclipse) but I would like to turn it on ONLY for specific file types - say *.mf files.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, this doesn't seem to be fully supported.
This was ["vehemently" asked in 2010](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257313#c19):

> > Can we consider that the global approach:
> > all text editors show whitespace characters or not"
> > is COMPLETELY wrong ?
>
> NO (I hope the big letters make it easier for you to get it ;-)
>
> Now having said that, every editor (type) can decide to override the default options by either, always enable/disable them or by adding additional options.
> If you need this from e.g. the CDT editor then you should file a bug report there. If you desire to set this per editor (or rather content type) then please file a new enhancement request. This bug will not deal with this.

Hence the current enhancement request "[bug 321439 'Allow whitespace options per content type'](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321439).
(and not too many volunteers to tackle said request)