# Show whitespace characters in standard output

Tags: java, eclipse, whitespace

Display whitespace characters in Eclipse is [a simple trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364168/show-some-invisible-whitespace-characters-in-eclipse), but unfortunately this applies only on Editor views.

[image]

Is there a way to display these characters in the Console view too? I would find it useful for checking if strings are correctly formatted. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'whitespace characters'? Can you provide an example?

Comment: If I understand correctly, @Roddy, OP wants whitespace displayed visibly in the console output.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I was curious whether the OP intended whitespace like `\t`, etc, or like some text-editors provide where a ␣ or dot represent a single space and a right arrow represents a tab.

Comment: @Roddy If I guess correctly, either will do, since both allow to check the formatting. But of course I might guess wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there was a bit of confusion regarding the term "whitespace characters", I will attempt to cover both possible instances.

If you wish to display such things as new lines and tabs, Java Strings include special characters for these constructs. `\n` will display a newline (line break). `\t` will display a tab. `\r` is a carriage return. There are others, as shown in the table [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but these are the most common.

Alternatively, if you intended displaying whitespace as a visible character, this is a different issue entirely. In this situation, I am assuming you wish to display a tab as an arrow or a space between words as a dot, like some text editors do. As far as I know, there is no built-in capability for this.

You could, however, replace existing whitespace with a unicode character that you want to represent that type of whitespace. The Java `String` class supports the use of unicode characters; it would just be a matter of finding the one you wish to use to indicate, say, a tab and then replacing all instances of `\t` with that symbol.

Comment: Yes, the second instance is the correct one :) maybe someone knows how to do it, or maybe already exist a Java function that replaces the characters...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/04.html

In short: You can use \r, \t, \f, and \n in the console text output for the needed whitespace. \t = Tab, \n = New line and etc. Check out the link for more details.

Comment: thank you, but isn't what i have asked :) please see edited question