# Eclipse: Turn off Java editor indentation feature

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I seem to have turned on a feature by mistake in by Eclipse Java editor.

It seems to be related to indentation, but I don't know the name of the feature, so cannot turn it off!

See attached screenshot with the dots indicating indentation and an icon for each newline.

What is the name of this feature so I can turn it off?

Comment: Duplicate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364168/show-some-invisible-whitespace-characters-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon with paragraph symbol "show whitespace characters" (the one for end of line) turns this feature on and off.