# Strange symbols are showing in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My friend used my laptop for a while and I forgot to close Eclipse, Later on when I started to work on my project, its showing strange symbols like ">>" and some sort of "q", can any one tell me how to remove this? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your friend has turned on the display of invisible characters. You can turn them off: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/364199/1864610) has the details

Comment: The ">>" signifies a tab and the "q"-like symbol is a line break.  They won't affect your code at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show SOME invisible/whitespace characters in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364168/show-some-invisible-whitespace-characters-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response guys. I know that won't affect my code but that was really annoying, its gone now, Thanks :)

Comment: "invisible characters" are also known as whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

You need to click (actually un-click) one button with symbol of Pi.

[image]

Characters you see are symbols of tabulations and line breaks (normally invisible).

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is displaying all whitespace characters. Use

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
```

and uncheck the "whitespace characters" checkbox to hide them